# bootstrap 4 internal css modification

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm new to bootstrap. Can anyone lend some insight on how to modify bootstrap. I created a example site but having trouble modifying after basic bootstrap. I have "container" and have the font blue but when I created another container "container new-place" and try to modify  with interal css it doesn't work. Can I create my own "custom" bootstrap classes? How do I change the text of lets say I have ten "container new-place" and five "container" how can i modify each group?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        h1 {

            color:yellow;
        }

        .container{

            color:blue;
        }

        .container new-place {

            color:red;
        }


    </style>

    <title>Practice Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>


        <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
            <div class="container">
                <h1 class="display-3">Fluid jumbo heading</h1>
                <p class="lead">Jumbo helper text</p>
                <hr class="my-2">
                <p>More info</p>
                <p class="lead">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="Jumbo action link" role="button">Jumbo action name</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container new-place" date-time="00:00">
            <h1>hello</h1>
        </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. It maybe because bootstrap is using a higher precedence than your custom CSS. If you're not very familiar about CSS precedence, You can put your custom style in each and every elements you want to change (in-line style CSS). `<div class="container" style="border: 1px solid red;"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, but the implementation is slightly wrong.

For example

```
<div class="container new-place" date-time="00:00">
    <h1>hello</h1>
</div>
```

You have created a style which combines two classes. This is correct as it will have a greater specificity and allow you to override the Bootstrap style. The css is incorrect. You have

```
.container new-place {
   color:red;
}
```

The css should be

```
.container.new-place {
    color:red;
}
```

Now the style will apply correctly.

Comment: Hey thank you for the response but that didn't work I tried a few things and the only thing that worked was to combine classes with a "-" so   ``` 
        <div class="container-new-place" date-time="00:00">
            <h1 class="h1 container new-place">Picker</h1>
            <input type="number" name="" id="">
        </div>
        <div>
            ```  needed to be this in the internal css ``` .container.new-place {
            color:red;
        }   ``` to make the color of the text red.

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to achieve. If you were trying to make the h1 red then you were styling the wrong element (div). If you want to change the colour of the h1 then add a style to the h1 :D

Answer (score 0):

You can. Use `!important`. For example:

```
.container{
    color:blue !important;
}
.new-place {
    color:red !important;
}
```